# Getting two data from two different forms to create a scoreboard using C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a project work and I need to make my program better. How my program work is the user will login with their username and password. If they do not have an account, they will register for one. Once they login, they will be able to play the game. The game is a number guessing game which requires them to guess a random number within the range given. They are given a limited number of tries and the system will calculate the score.

However, now i am trying to make a scoreboard which will display the top ten scores. The scoreboard can be access by clicking a button in the game form. But the problem I can't seem to get both the username and score into the scoreBoardForm. The username is in the login form while the score is in the game form. The score is being shown in a label in scoreBoardForm.

The rest of the program works fine other than the scoreBoardForm. Please help. Thank you!

Here's a rough coding I have.

```
    string strUserName = LoginForm.strName;
    int intPoints = GuessingGameForm.intScore; 

    private void highscore()
    {
         int intCount = 0, intIndex;
        for (intIndex = 0; intIndex <= intCount; intIndex++)
        {
            intCount++;
        }
        scoreBoardLabel.Text = intIndex.ToString() + ". " + strUserName + "      " + intPoints.ToString() + "\n";
    }
```

I'n not sure whether which part is wrong. Somehow, the data for strName and intScore won't come over to this form.

Comment: Welcome to the SO. It's quite difficult to get any help without providing a few lines of code and explaining using them your problem. So please, post your code (not all your code, but where you face with this problem). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show some research work from your side wha have you done by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your data of your high score table stored?
My hint would be:

- make list of played games (name of player, score, date?...)
- after ending a game you make a new entry in this list.
- sort it after score, trim it (if you only want to save the top 10 or so)
- save it to disk.

by opening your hight score form, you only have to load the file and display the content.